# Could not find method leftShift() for arguments after updating studio 3.4

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After updating studio `3.4` and Gradle version to `5.1.1` I got the error on my task as **Could not find method leftShift()**

**My task:**

```
task incrementBetaVersion << {
    println("Incrementing Beta Version Number...")
    incrementVersionNumber('BetaVersionNumber')
    println("Incrementing Beta Version Number...")
    incrementVersionName('BetaVersionName')
}
```

I got the error for the left shift operator `<<` in the line.

How to resolve this error?

Comment: << was deprecated in 4.x and removed in 5.0

Answer (score 283, accepted):

To solve this error, change `<<` with `doLast` like this.

```
task incrementBetaVersion  {
    doLast {
        println("Incrementing Beta Version Number...")
        incrementVersionNumber('BetaVersionNumber')
        println("Incrementing Beta Version Number...")
        incrementVersionName('BetaVersionName')
    }
}
```

Left shift operator represent's `doLast { }`.

> `<<` was deprecated in Gradle 4.x and removed in Gradle 5.0

**From Docs:**

`<<` for task definitions no longer works. In other words, you can not use the syntax

`task myTask << { …​ }`.

Use the `Task.doLast()` method instead, like this:

```
task myTask {
    doLast {
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

More info here:
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/could-not-find-method-leftshift-for-arguments-on-task-of-type-org-gradle-api-defaulttask/30614

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_4.html#changes_5.0

Comment: where is this? which file?

Comment: in build.gradle

Comment: @BhuvaneshBS Where it prints?

Comment: In Terminal while running the task

Answer (score 45):

### Just Remove "<<" from Task and add your code in `doLast{}`

For solution of `Could not find method leftShift() for arguments on task of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask`

```
task incrementBetaVersion << {
   // your code
}
```

to

```
task incrementBetaVersion {
   doLast {
      // your code
    }
}
```

Reference https://discuss.gradle.org/t/could-not-find-method-leftshift-for-arguments-on-task-of-type-org-gradle-api-defaulttask/30614/2

> << (`LeftShift()`)  operator is deprecated in 4.x `Gradle` and Removed in 5.x `Gradle` Version.

Answer (score 9):

It happening because of the Left Shift operator has been replaced by doLast { }.

```
<< has deprecated in 4.x and removed in 5.0 version
```

Now you will have to change the code:

```
task incrementBetaVersion << {
    println("Incrementing Beta Version Number...")
    incrementVersionNumber('BetaVersionNumber')
    println("Incrementing Beta Version Number...")
    incrementVersionName('BetaVersionName')
}
```

to

```
task incrementBetaVersion  {
    doLast {
        println("Incrementing Beta Version Number...")
        incrementVersionNumber('BetaVersionNumber')
        println("Incrementing Beta Version Number...")
        incrementVersionName('BetaVersionName')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

To solve this error is pretty simple.

Just replace `<<` with `doLast`

See below updated code, today I fix in my cordova Android project.

```
task cdvPrintProps {
   doLast {
       //your code
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this error in a Kotlin project that is using `MockMaker` to mock non final classes.

The solution is to change the old syntax to this new one:

```
task createTestResources {
    description = "Allows Mocking non-final classes and data classes in a Kotlin project"
    doLast {
        def mockMakerFile = new File("$projectDir/src/test/resources/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker")
        if (System.env.MOCK_MAKER != null) {
            logger.info("Using MockMaker ${System.env.MOCK_MAKER}")
            mockMakerFile.parentFile.mkdirs()
            mockMakerFile.createNewFile()
            mockMakerFile.write(System.env.MOCK_MAKER)
        } else {
            logger.info("Using default MockMaker")
        }
    }
}
```

Note that a few things have changed, like including the `doLast` block, and removing the `<<` from the task signature. It works for me now. Hope it does for you too :-)