# Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.60-eap-25

Tags: android, cordova, kotlin, jetbrains-ide

While trying to import my Cordova android project to the android studio I got below error, how can rectify this issue

Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.60-eap-25.

ERROR: Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.60-eap-25.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.60-eap-25/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.60-eap-25.pom
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.60-eap-25/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.60-eap-25.jar
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.60-eap-25/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.60-eap-25.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.60-eap-25/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.60-eap-25.jar
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.60-eap-25/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.60-eap-25.pom
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.60-eap-25/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.60-eap-25.jar
Required by:
    unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0-alpha01
    unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0-alpha01 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.0-alpha01
    unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0-alpha01 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:27.0.0-alpha01
    unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0-alpha01 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:4.0.0-alpha01
    unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0-alpha01 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:4.0.0-alpha01
    unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0-alpha01 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.0-alpha01 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.0.0-alpha01
    unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0-alpha01 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.0-alpha01 > com.android.tools:common:27.0.0-alpha01
    unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0-alpha01 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.0-alpha01 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:27.0.0-alpha01
    unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0-alpha01 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.0-alpha01 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:27.0.0-alpha01
    unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0-alpha01 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.0-alpha01 > com.android.tools:sdklib:27.0.0-alpha01 > com.android.tools:repository:27.0.0-alpha01
    unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0-alpha01 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.0-alpha01 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.0.0-alpha01 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:27.0.0-alpha01

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58536638/4967034). Long story short, the way Cordova declares its Gradle dependency fetches the most recent version, which in this case requires some Kotlin stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The only viable solution that worked for me was to delete **~/.gradle/caches** directory.

Also, put `maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }` in `allProjects` as well as `repositories` block.

Answer (score -1):

Please add the below line of code in cordova plugin add cordova-support-google-services
gradle file should contain : ----

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
}
```

}

```
ext.postBuildExtras = {
if (project.extensions.findByName('googleServices') == null) {        
    apply plugin: com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin
}
```

}